# stop showing the save dialog box when excuting OnKey code Problem with SendKeys"{f2}"

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a macro for change numberformat cells into AlHijri Calendar and I have it call by OnKey method.
but when pressing the keystroke the save dialogue box appears then the macro executed.I have tried many keystroke.

```
Sub ToHijri()    
  With Selection
  .NumberFormat = "[$-1970000]B2dd/mm/yyyy;@"
  End With
Dim Cel As Range
Dim Selectedr As Range
   Set Selectedr = Application.Selection
   For Each Cel In Selectedr.Cells
 SendKeys "{f2}"
 SendKeys "{enter}"
   Next Cel
  'ThisWorkbook.Save
 End Sub
```

this a piece of code for call the macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.OnKey "%h", "ToHijri"
End Sub
```

any suggestion to prevent the save dialogue from showing.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was    That is `SendKeys "{F2}"` doesn't work properly when it used with `OnKey` with any combination of Shift or Alt or Ctrl. The solve of the problem using F3 with OnKey.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the opening save dialog behaviour, maybe it's your office regional/language settings.

But I found that in order to disable the default behaviour of Alt +  commands, you have to hide the ribbon through an excel 4 macro.

My suggestion is to consider using ctrl or another keystroke instead of Alt.

Here they say that disabling just the alt key is not possible:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/VBA-for-deactivating-just-the-ALT-key/td-p/203577

See code with workaround:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

    ' Assign the macro to Alt + H
    Application.OnKey "%h", "RunMacroName"

    ' Hide the Ribbon
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",false)"

End Sub



Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    ' Back top it's normal state
    Application.OnKey "%h"

    ' Show back the Ribbon
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",true)"


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Ricado Diaz I tried ctr - shift - alt with all possibilities but all of them give an unwanted procedure and hiding the ribbon didn't work.

Comment: What’s your ms-office language?

Comment: it's english. I will try the code on another computer.

Comment: Try to set a break point at the beginning of the macro and step into each line

Comment: thank you @Ricardo Diaz  I am sorry for being late. this line < SendKeys "{f2}" >  is cause of this problem when I omitted every thing goes correctly. and I searched for another code but I didn't find.

Comment: When you press directly the F2 key in the keyboard does it have the same behavior?

Comment: Why are you using those keys to edit the cells?
SendKeys "{f2}"
SendKeys "{enter}"
Seems unnecesary, but are you having trouble in order to set the new format into the cells?

Comment: Thanks @Ricado Diaz. . the F2 key gives the normal result it changes from enter mode into edit mode for cells without any strange behavior.I need this tow lines SendKeys "{f2}" SendKeys "{enter}". After I change the format of cells by this code  With Selection
  .NumberFormat = "[$-1970000]B2dd/mm/yyyy;@"
  End With. but the new format to be activated need to enter the cells by double click or F2 then exit the cells by enter or the mouse.so I used these extra code.

Comment: Sounds like there is something else inside your workbook or in it's settings that is preventing a proper update of the format. I tried to reproduce the behaviour you mentioned but I couldn't. If it doesn't have sensitive data, you could share it, Or remove it and leave just the cells with dates.

Comment: Try to copy and paste the macro in a new workbook just to discard that is a file-related problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo Diaz The macro works correctly except F2.There are Tow steps for changeing into AlHijri calendar cause Excel considers Alhijri as text. First - change the format cell from text into date. Second- Double click or F2 and enter to activate the new format and show the cell's contents with the new format.  you must click into each cell to get that. I have found a video on Youtube that explains these steps. I tried the macro on another computer with many new sheets but all of them require the same steps.

Comment: I don't have file with certain data I want to make a macro which I can apply it in future with files that have a huge data.

Comment: Can you share the link to the youtube video pls?

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo Diaz  [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82JwdlgSpgs&t=0s&list=LLlRpctPPlCn_UfgLIXOjd-g&index=4)

Comment: I try to use double click instead of F2